# Added a large file to a git branch, committed changes, now the file is in every branch (including master)

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm at a point where I realized I took some actions that were the equivalent of entering a cave without a flashlight.  Hopefully this retelling of events will contain an indication of what went wrong.

I began at my project's master branch.  I performed a `git pull` from the remote master (to make sure I had the most recent build), then a `git checkout -b newFeature`.  With this `newFeature` branch, I made some changes, including adding a 700mb `.mp4` file.  I then committed my changes with `git commit -a -m "New features and a big mp4 file..."`  I never pushed the changes to the remote.  Made some more changes, decided I didn't want them, so I did a `git stash` at the end of the day.

This morning, I switched to `master` branch, where I did a `git/status`.  I noticed my local master branch was now ahead of the remote master, which was odd because they should have been exactly the same.  I also noticed that when I built my iOS app (from `master`, NOT `newFeature`) that the app size was 700mb bigger than it should have been.

Now this part is where I started panicking, so I apologize if the order of events is not completely accurate...

- I saw that my .mp4 file was an unstaged file after running `git status`.
- I tried to do a `git reset HEAD <file>`, which seemed to remove the file, but it still showed up in my builds.
- I then tried `git rebase`, but never got through it because I seemed to hit a loop where all `git rebase --continue` did was end up at the same place over and over, so I aborted (I've never done a rebase before).
- Giving up, I deleted all of my local files (or at least I think I did), restarted my computer (you never know), cloned everything from GitHub... and my builds are still including the large mp4 file.

I cannot seem to find the mp4 file, though it is clearly there when I build the app.  I never pushed it to the remote, not that it would have let me anyway due to GitHub's restraints.

Any solutions, bread crumbs, or whatever would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I attempted to go back to the build before I ever made the `newFeature` branch using  git reset --hard , still no luck, as my project will still build with the mp4 file.

Perhaps I could find where this mp4 file is store locally?  I can not find it in my project folder.

**SOLVED**:
See my answer below... long story short, I needed to Clean my build in Xcode (Cmd-shift-K) to remove the MP4 from the build folder.

Comment: `git commit -a` only commits changed-but-*tracked* files.  If the mp4 file is new, it will not have been `git add`-ed.  You can look at the tree in the commit to see if it's there (eg, `git show newFeature:` and `git show newFeature:subdir` to see what's in the directories).

Comment: So I can see the commit that contains the mp4 file.  Running `git show <commit-number>:myMovie.mp4` gives me the following `fatal: Path 'myMovie.mp4' does not exist in <commit-number>`

Comment: That means the mp4 file is not in fact in the commit (not that this is relevant to the rest of the Xcode problem, already solved I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's something I should have done right from the get-go.  I've read before, "Before building your project, do a Clean on your build" (Cmd-Shift-K in Xcode).  After running a disk report on my drive (using [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/jdiskreport/)), I found the mp4 file cached in Xcode's `DerivedData` folder in my `Library` folder.  Doing a Clean on the build removed the file from this folder, and no other future builds included it.

I guess I never ran across a time when not performing a `Clean` was really evident.  When I was restarting Xcode, I wrongly assumed any sort of cache clearing would be done then.

So turns out this wasn't a problem with git directly, but with Xcode.  I'm not sure if it should be the correct behavior or not, but I will now be run a Clean whenever switching between branches.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`git clean`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) to remove any extra files.  You should also check the logs of your build system to find out where this file is getting included.

Comment: Tried that to no success... also just tried `git clean -f myMovie.mp4` to no avail.  I'll look into if I can see where in Xcode it's still getting included in the build.  I can clearly see it being added to the build, but can't find any references left to it in the project.